# Buscando dados via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho uma API rodando local com o endereço http://localhost:8080/core-web/rest/usuarios/79. O número 79 no final é o id do usuário.

Esta API que é em JAVA me retorna os seguintes dados:

```
{
    "id": 79,
    "nome": "Francis",
    "sobrenome": "",
    "sexo": "M",
    "email": "francisvagnerdaluz@gmail.com",
    "senha": "8D969EEF6ECAD3C29A3A629280E686CF0C3F5D5A86AFF3CA12020C923ADC6C92",
    "cpf": "035.699.346-21",
    "perfil": null,
    "cep": "35162-000",
    "rua": "Vila Celeste",
    "bairro": "Vila Celeste",
    "cidade": "Ipatinga",
    "estado": "mg",
    "dataNascimento": "1980-10-23",
    "grauEscolaridade": null,
    "telefone": null,
    "celular": null,
    "quantidadeConvite": null,
    "imagem": null
}
```

Esta é a minha função GET:

```
function get(url) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {

    if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if(xhr.status == 200) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      } else {
        reject(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  };

  xhr.send();
  });
}
```

então quando eu chamo essa função passando o endereço  tipo get('http://localhost:8080/core-web/rest/usuarios/79'); ela mostra no console.log os dados como estão acima.

Então quero filtrar os dados e selecionar somente o nome ou qualquer outro dado para preencher por exemplo uma tag h1 na minha view. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O json resultado tem uma lista de usuários ou um só usuário ? Aconselho a colocar um json de exemplo para que seja claro como o tratar, assim como o código de javascript com ajax que está a utilizar para obter o json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa criar um [Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) com o JSON que foi retornado da requisição e acessa-lo com seguinte sintaxe `User.nome` como [nesse exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_objects_object) e depois inserir na tag que você deseja, seja pelo ID ou Classe, no caso usei o [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)  do Javascript.

```js
var User = {
    "id": 79,
    "nome": "Francis",
    "sobrenome": "",
    "sexo": "M",
    "email": "francisvagnerdaluz@gmail.com",
    "senha": "8D969EEF6ECAD3C29A3A629280E686CF0C3F5D5A86AFF3CA12020C923ADC6C92",
    "cpf": "035.699.346-21",
    "perfil": null,
    "cep": "35162-000",
    "rua": "Vila Celeste",
    "bairro": "Vila Celeste",
    "cidade": "Ipatinga",
    "estado": "mg",
    "dataNascimento": "1980-10-23",
    "grauEscolaridade": null,
    "telefone": null,
    "celular": null,
    "quantidadeConvite": null,
    "imagem": null
}

document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = User.nome;
```

```html
<h1 id="nome"> </h1>
```